# Sum two fields in the same table

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a table named bills. in the table one field is amount and another field is bill_amount_left. I want to sum up the bill_amount_left when a new bill is added. If a bill is created against an user then, users previous bill_amount_left will be automatically increased with the new bill. How to do that?

```
$data = $this->validate([
    'property_id' => 'required',
    'amount' => 'required',
    'due_date' => 'required',
    'start_date' => 'required',
    'end_date' => 'required',
    'bill_type' => 'required',
    'remark' => 'required',
]);
$data['amount_left'] = $data['amount'];        
$bill = Bill::create($data);
```

I am using these code to create a bill. So, I need to update the amount_left field every time a new bill is created. Also I need to identify against which property they bill is created. For example a bill is created against property_id 1. Then another bill created against property_id 1. So the field amount_left should automatically increased with newly created bill.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data['amount_left'] = Bill::where('user_id', 1)->sum('amount_left') + $data['amount'];
```

or you can simply sum all of the user bills with

```
$bill = Bill::where('user_id', 1)->sum('amount_left');
```

so you dont need to store the current bills + incoming bill to database.

you just need to store the incoming bill which you can show the sum of all the user bills with `$bill`